# How can I correctly pause a game involving physics and transitions?

Tags: lua, coronasdk, game-physics

I want to include a pause button in my game which involves physics on the objects and some transitions. How can I do that in Corona SDK, to which I am fairly new?
 Any guidance??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function pause()

physics.pause()
end

Runtime:addEventListener("touch", pause)
```

will pause all physics.

```
function pause(event)
    if event.phase == "began" then
        if paused == false then
             physics.pause()
             paused = true
        elseif paused == true then
             physics.start()
             paused = false
        end
   end
end

paused = false
Runtime:addEventListener("touch", pause)
```

will toggle physics pause on click

Answer (score 2):

Besides stopping physics, you also have to remove the enterframe listeners, if you have objects that moves with the scene, and any animation you have in the game.

So your pause function would be like that

```
function Pause(event)
 if event.phase == "began" then
    if paused == false then

      physics.pause()
      paused = true

      Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame",Contador_func)
      Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame",Move_c1ScrollPai)
      Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame",Move_c1ScrollFilho)
      Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame",VelAumenta)
      Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame",Serra)  
      Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame",passaro)
      Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame",bf)
      Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame",bf2) 
      Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame",p)        
      Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame",CR)        
      Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame",Funcao)
      Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame",BumPassaro)
      Runtime:removeEventListener("collision",Andar)

      p:pause()
      Bum:pause()
      coin:pause()
      coins:pause()

    elseif paused == true then

      Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",Contador_func)
      Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",Move_c1ScrollPai)
      Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",Move_c1ScrollFilho)
      Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",VelAumenta)
      Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",Serra)  
      Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",passaro)
      Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",bf)
      Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",bf2) 
      Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",p)        
      Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",CR)        
      Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",Funcao)
      Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",BumPassaro)
      Runtime:addEventListener("collision",Andar)
      Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame",p)

      p:play()
      Bum:play()
      coin:play()
      coins:play()

      physics.start()
      paused = false

    end
 end
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

With physics.pause() there will be a slight *jitter* in the physics object.

Another way is to capture the screen when paused and put it over the scene.

After that you put on top of the screen the paused screen GUI objects.

Remove the paused screen objects and the screen capture when resume.

```
local gameScene= display.newGroup()

local myObject1 = display.newRect(50,50,100,150 )
gameScene:insert(myObject1)

function onPause(event)
    local screenCap = display.captureScreen(false) --dont save to album
    gameScene:insert(screenCap)

    --insert pause buttons and etc here
end

Runtime:addEventListener("touch",onPause)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use pause button to set function:

```
local function pausebtn(event)

if event.phase == "ended" then
      physics.pause()

   end
pausebtn:addEventListener("touch", pausebtn)
```